# Unable to link the output (static library) of an external git CMake project to a CMake project

Tags: c++, git, linker, cmake, static-libraries

I'm having trouble trying to link a library that I recently pushed onto Git to my CMake project.

I have named the library `octal` ([GitHub](https://github.com/TheOctopod/octal-cpp)) and am trying to link it to my other library `bulletframe` ([GitHub](https://github.com/hf-studio/bulletframe)). Both projects are created by me.

I anticipated that linking the library wouldn't work the first time, so I only started off with a couple of source files in `octal`. The folder structure of `octal` is as follows:

```
.gitignore
CMakeLists.txt
.git/
build/ # generated project files go here, but right now it's empty
src/
    CMakeLists.txt
    octal.h # this is empty
    octal/
        vector/
            vector.h
            vector.cpp
```

**octal/CMakeLists.txt**

```
#...

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}")

add_subdirectory("src")
```

**octal/src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
macro(add_include)
    set(ALL_INCLUDES ${ALL_INCLUDES} ${ARGV})
endmacro(add_include)

add_include("octal.h")
add_include("octal/vector/vector.cpp" "octal/vector/vector.h")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${ALL_INCLUDES})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
```

**octal/src/vector/vector.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace octal
{
    class Vector
    {
        // ...
        Vector Add(Vector other);
        Vector Subtract(Vector other);
        Vector Multiply(Vector other);
        Vector Multiply(double x);
        Vector Divide(Vector other);
        Vector Divide(double x);
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

These configurations are successful in building a `liboctal.a` file, however I'm not sure if they are linked with `bulletframe` correctly. There are multiple files that use classes from `octal`, but this is the first error that it gives after it tries to compile the first source file, `entity.cpp`:

```
fatal error: octal/vector/vector.h: No such file or directory
 #include "octal/vector/vector.h"
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
src\CMakeFiles\bulletframe.dir\build.make:57: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bulletframe.dir/entity.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bulletframe.dir/entity.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:121: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bulletframe.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bulletframe.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:133: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bulletframe.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bulletframe.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'bulletframe' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [bulletframe] Error 2
```

`bulletframe` has a similar folder structure to `octal`

**bulletframe/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
include(ExternalProject)
set(EXPROJ_DIR    "${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/external")
set(LIB_DIR       "${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/lib")

set(OCTAL_NAME          "octal-git")
set(OCTAL_GIT           "https://github.com/TheOctopod/octal-cpp.git")
set(OCTAL_PREFIX        "${EXPROJ_DIR}/${OCTAL_NAME}")
set(OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR    "${EXPROJ_DIR}/${OCTAL_NAME}")
set(OCTAL_BUILD_DIR     "${EXPROJ_DIR}/${OCTAL_NAME}/build")
set(OCTAL_INSTALL_DIR   "${LIB_DIR}")

ExternalProject_Add(${OCTAL_NAME}
    PREFIX          ${OCTAL_PREFIX}
    TMP_DIR         ${OCTAL_PREFIX}-tmp
    STAMP_DIR       ${OCTAL_PREFIX}-stamp
    # - Download Step ------------------
    GIT_REPOSITORY  ${OCTAL_GIT}
    # - Update Step --------------------
    UPDATE_COMMAND  ""
    # - Configure Step -----------------
    SOURCE_DIR      ${OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR}
    # - Build Step ---------------------
    BINARY_DIR      ${OCTAL_BUILD_DIR}
    # - Install Step ------------------
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    CMAKE_ARGS
    "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
)

add_library("octal" STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties("octal" PROPERTIES
    # this is where ExternalProject built liboctal.a at
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OCTAL_BUILD_DIR}/src"
)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

**bulletframe/src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
macro(add_include)
    set(ALL_INCLUDES ${ALL_INCLUDES} ${ARGV})
endmacro(add_include)

add_include("entity.cpp")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${ALL_INCLUDES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "octal")
```

---

As it stands, my current configurations are unable to build `bulletframe` with both the `Visual Studio 10 2013` and `MinGW Makefiles` generators.

A couple concerns come to mind as I witnessed the compiler giving similar errors every time:

- **Am I not building the static library (`octal`) correctly?**
- **Am I not linking it to my project (`bulletframe`) correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're building octal OK, but aren't providing proper paths to its sources (for bulletframe to be able to `#include` it) nor to its compiled library.

Fixing the includes issue is simple; just add the path to the imported library's [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) property.  However, fixing the library's path is a little trickier.

With MSVC, the full path to the octal lib will be

```
${OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/<build type>/octal.lib
```

where `<build type>` is "Debug", "Release", etc.  However, with other compilers, the path will be

```
${OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/liboctal.a
```

To get round this, I'd do something like:

```
add_library(octal STATIC IMPORTED)
if(MSVC)
  set_target_properties(octal PROPERTIES
      IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Debug/octal.lib"
      IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Release/octal.lib"
      INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
else()
  set_target_properties(octal PROPERTIES
      IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/liboctal.a"
      INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${OCTAL_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
endif()
```

Comment: Funny you mentioned the if-statement -- I actually just added a check for `MSVC`. However, one thing I'm confused about is why I would need to define the source files of `octal`. Having `octal.lib` or `liboctal.a` is not enough? If I could just directly include the sources, why bother compiling a library? Anyways, thanks for answering and I'll try the solution later on.

Comment: Your solution worked -- though I still would appreciate some clarification on the concern stated in the previous comment. Unless you'd rather have me make another question on that?

Comment: Really all we're *wanting* to expose is the public headers of octal, not the full list of sources.  See for example [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29315458/2556117) which gives my opinion on how to structure a library's source files.  Since octal's public headers are in the same path as the sources, we need to just give that path.  A major advantage of having octal as a self-contained library are that it doesn't need to be compiled multiple times even if it's included by multiple targets.

Comment: is it because the linked library is `IMPORTED` that I am required to define the include directory explicitly like that using `set_target_properties`, or is it just common practice? I can't, say, have the include directory already inside `octal.lib` as `target_include_directories` would seem to imply in your linked answer?

Comment: Yes - it's because it's imported.  The first paragraph of [the docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) tries to explain the rationale.