# Creating and using a library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to learn CMake, but I can't get to grips with the tutorials that are available.

Let's say my project has the structure below, and I want to make my_lib available through its CMakeLists file and use it in my main.cpp, what would my CMakeLists files look like?

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── externals
│   └── my_lib
│       └── src
│           ├── CMakeLists.txt
│           ├── MyClass.h
│           └── MyClass.cpp
└── main.cpp
```

Should I use include_directories or add_subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the directory structure you indicated, your CMakeLists.txt files could look like this:

/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Main)
add_subdirectory(externals/my_lib/src)
add_executable(my_main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_main my_lib)
```

/externals/my_lib/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(MyLib)
add_library(my_lib MyClass.cpp MyClass.h)
target_include_directories(my_lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Using `PUBLIC` in the `target_include_directories` call means that not only does your library have this as an "include path", but so does any target linking to it.

The downside with this setup however is that you're also going to expose any internal headers of `my_lib` to consuming targets too.  Say you also have an "Internal.h" as part of `my_lib` which you don't want to expose.  You can do this by moving the intentionally-public headers into a separate folder, e.g. "include":

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── externals
│   └── my_lib
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── include
│       │   └── MyClass.h
│       └── src
│           ├── Internal.h
│           └── MyClass.cpp
└── main.cpp
```

Your top-level CMakeLists.txt wouldn't change, but /externals/my_lib/CMakeLists.txt (which has moved up a level) now reads:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(MyLib)
add_library(my_lib src/MyClass.cpp src/Internal.h include/MyClass.h)
target_include_directories(my_lib
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    )
```

Now, since your library's "src" folder is `PRIVATE` to `my_lib`, main.cpp won't be able to `#include "Internal.h"`.

Comment: Thank you, this made thing alot clearer, and it actually worked! Am I right to assume that any files in the include dir can now use Internal.h?

Comment: The "include" dir would normally only contain headers.  These headers should only `#include` other headers in the "include" dir.  Say "MyClass.h" cointained `#include "Internal.h"`.  That would be a problem for anything depending on `my_lib` e.g. say "main.cpp" had `#include "MyClass.h"`.  The compiler knows where to find "MyClass.h" - we've told it about "externals/my_lib/include", but it can't find "Internal.h" which "MyClass.h" needs.  So, none of the headers in "include" should refer to files in "src".

Comment: If there's no way to avoid exposing "Internal.h" (often the case with template code) it's normal to place this in a subdirectory of "include" named "detail" to indicate to consumers of the library that it's sort of private code that may change without warning and shouldn't really be `#include`ed directly by them.